# Reference for representation theory of classical groups over arbitrary fields

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, representation-theory, algebraic-groups

I am looking for a reference for the representation theory of (classical) algebraic groups, that would ideally be something like the second part of Jantzen's "Representations of Algebraic Groups", but with a treatment over arbitrary fields (especially: of non-split classical groups). It might very well be that there is no such book currently, in which case I would welcome a reference to some well-written articles that give a good idea of what is currently known, and the basic methods.

Answer (score 1):

I think probably what you might want is in some articles of Tits. You can look in [1, §25.d] for an overview of these results with references.

**References:**

[1] Milne, J.S., 2017. Algebraic groups: The theory of group schemes of finite type over a field (Vol. 170). Cambridge University Press.