# Books on representation theory of algebraic groups

Tags: representation-theory, algebraic-groups

I would like to know the best books on the representation theory of algebraic groups. For a beginner? For an expert? Thanks.

Comment: [Jens Carsten Jantzen](https://bookstore.ams.org/surv-107-s/).

Comment: See also some posts here, e.g., [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3967864/reference-for-representation-theory-of-classical-groups-over-arbitrary-fields?rq=1).

Answer (score 0):

Beginner:

- Gunter Malle, Donna Testerman: Linear algebraic groups and finite groups of Lie type.
- Robert Steinberg: Lectures on Chevalley groups.
- Armand Borel: Properties and linear representations of Chevalley groups (Lecture notes in math 131)

More advanced:

- Jens Carsten Jantzen: Representations of algebraic groups. Second edition.
- James E. Humphreys: Modular representations of finite groups of Lie type.